# httpPost Method

Tags: java, http, http-post, httpclient

I am creating httpClient and when I send httpPost method, how can I attach a body to the httpRequest ??

```
 public String httpPost(String URL, String BODY) {

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);



    try {

        response = httpclient.execute(httpPost); // get response from executing client

        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            body.append(statusLine + "\n");
            HttpEntity e = response.getEntity();
            String entity = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            body.append(entity);

        } else {
            body.append(statusLine + "\n");
            // System.out.println(statusLine);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        httpPost.releaseConnection();
    }
    return body.toString();
}
```

For example, the string is
     " < html > < header > Header < /header> < body> I am body < /body>  "
Where do I attach that string to the request message ?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `StringEntity`, set it to the `HttpPost` object, and set the correct `Content-Type`:

```
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("data=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(body, "utf-8"));
entity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```

And then send your POST request as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `httpPost.setEntity(" < html > < header > Header < /header> < body> I am body < /body> ")` before your try-catch?

I'm not entirely sure what "entity" refers to, but that's the best I can come up with from looking at the documentation **[here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html)**

Comment: setEntity method takes Entity only ... I am wondering how to parse a string into an entity..